# C# Bad performance drawing image

Tags: c#, image, winforms, performance, drawing

When using normal FillEclipse function, my game has quite good fps. When I switch to using images I get terrible fps and the whole thing is laggy.

Here is my code, first I load the images (happens only once):

```
private Bitmap PlanetMe = new Bitmap("PlanetMe.png");
private Bitmap PlanetNeutral = new Bitmap("PlanetNeutral.png");
```

And I use them like this (which is called every paint event):

```
g.DrawImage(image, this.x - this.radius, this.y - this.radius, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Define your game. Is it WPF, WinForms, Xna, etc.? Otherwise we can't really help you.

Comment: It's a WinForms using a picturebox.

Comment: Perhaps a mismatch for DPI or something?

Comment: I am thinking, it might have something to do with my resizing of the image?

Comment: _I am thinking, it might have something to do with my resizing of the image?_ Yes. Try to cache the right size and use the cached images!

Comment: The problem is, that the size changes once a second or when player does an action... So I guess caching it wouldn't help.

Comment: Do you cache the bitmaps that you load? In other words, are you re-creating `PlanetMe` and `PlanetNeutral` each time you redraw, or only once at the beginning?

Comment: No, they are declared only once at the beginning and the only thing I do is DrawImage using them.

Comment: So there is no way to solve the resizing problem in winforms?

Comment: winforms is not a suitable platform for games (nor anything else I can think of). Use current, relevant, useful technology instead. If you're after serious game development, look at Unity or straight hardcore DirectX/OpenGL C++. Otherwise for simple 2D Windows stuff use WPF/XAML.

Comment: Yes, I usually use JS with canvas and I started unity. This was just a project for school.